# What's wrong with this "Guess my number" batch game?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I wrote this game. it simply sets a random number between 1 and 16 and the user must guess it. when the guess was correct, it shows the attempt count to the user.

But when I run it and enter a number, it displays an error and the close immediately. I think the error says missing something.

```
@echo off
color 0A

set /a key = %random% / 2048
set /a attempts=0

title Guess My Number (0 to 16)

:AGAIN
set /p in = Guess it.
set /a in = %in%

if %key% GTR %in% (
echo My Number is greater.
set /a attempts=%attempts%+1
goto again
)

if %key% LSS %in% (
echo My Number is less.
set /a attempts=%attempts%+1
goto again
)

if %key% == %in% (
echo right!
echo You Guessed it in %attempts% attempts.
goto end
)

:end
pause
```

Comment: post the error as well

Comment: remove the spaces before equal sign in `SET /P` lines. The spaces become part of variable name.

Comment: @CrakC I can't even read the error as it displays and closes too soon.

Comment: @npocmaka It says < was expected ... I couldn't read the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As npocmaka wrote, the error is that you have spacec in your `SET` statements. Removing them results in the following code which works perfectly:

```
@echo off
color 0A

set /a key =%random% / 2048
set /a attempts=0

title Guess My Number (0 to 16)

:AGAIN
set /p in=Guess it.
set /a in=%in%

if %key% GTR %in% (
    echo My Number is greater.
    set /a attempts=%attempts%+1
    goto again
)

if %key% LSS %in% (
    echo My Number is less.
    set /a attempts=%attempts%+1
    goto again
)

if %key%==%in% (
    echo right!
    echo You Guessed it in %attempts% attempts.
    goto end
)

:end
pause
```

EDIT: And by the way, your code is nonsense. The answer is always 2. :D I guess you need something like `set /a key=%random%%%16`

Comment: Thanks for editing your post from `set /a key=%random%%%2048` to what you got from my post, that was just gobstopper silly but his code doesn't always produce the answer 2. Put his first couple lines into a batch file. The numbers generate fine.

Comment: buuuhuuu TT Didn't even read your post, just noticed that it's 16 and not 2048. That's it. My solution was even already accepted as you posted your answer.

Comment: `set /a key=%random% / 2048` evaluates to a number `0 <= %key% <= 15`. Therefore, `title` should be _Guess My Number (0 to_ **15**_)_

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I'd do your little game

```
@echo off
color 0A
title Guess My Number (0 to 16)

:Start
set /a key=%random%%%16
set attempts=0

:again
set /p in=What is your guess? (0-16): 
set /a attempts+=1

if %key% GTR %in% (
    echo My Number is greater.
    goto again
)

if %key% LSS %in% (
    echo My Number is less.
    goto again
)

if %key% == %in% (
    echo CORRECT!
    echo You Guessed it in %attempts% attempts.
    pause
)
```

Your issue is already solved, with the extra spaces. But I used a different method to generate a random number up to 16, and I moved your attempts counter up to just below the `set /p` so it'll always be counting up one. In your current version, you have it set to only go up for incorrect guesses. I think it should count the final guess as well. Plus I shortened the attempts counter slightly for you, just a helpful tip for you in the future.

**-Edit-** I forgot to mention, you don't need this line at all `set /a in=%in%` as the variable `%in%` is already set with this line `set /p in=Guess it.` there's no need to set it twice.

Comment: the `set /a in=%in%` definitely makes sense. It makes sure, the variable is a number ("correcting" wrong or empty user Input)

Comment: How so? because this particular code, has no methods for verifying user input, so you could enter a letter, or no input, outcome is still going to be the same, with and without that line, so therefor, it's not necessary.

Comment: `set /a` will replace an empty Input with a Zero, avoiding Syntax Errors with the `if`s afterward. Any Letter or Letter-Number-combination will be converted to a number only, avoiding string-comparison (and probably wrong results) with the `if`s. So in the end, the `set /a`**is** the method for verifying user Input (or at least make it compatible with the following Code).

Comment: Pretty sure, this code works without the `set /a` regardless of user input. being alphanumeric or blank, Yup, just looked it over again, would you care to try it for yourself?

Comment: be sure, I did. Empty input gives syntax error. (in first run, afterwards, the variable is still set to the previous value)

Comment: Which happen regardless if that line is there, or if it isn't... It's unnecessary. So as I stated earlier. "_because this particular code, has no methods for verifying user input, so you could enter a letter, or no input, outcome is still going to be the same, with and without that line, so therefor, it's not necessary._"

Comment: If I can't get you to try it, I won't get you to believe me. Bye.

Comment: It seems that you're a special kind of special. The only reason you're done, is maybe because you realized that you've been wrong the entire time. But it's been fun @Stephan.

Comment: @Stephan `set /a in=in` makes sense in contrast to advised `set /a in=%in%` which raises `Missing operand` error if `in` variable is not defined and `Invalid number` error if `%in%` evaluates to e.g. `08` or `09`. Further examples of problematic `in` variable values: `5+`, `3 4 5` etc.